# Clear form data when user clicks back

Tags: php, html

How do I clear the contact form data when the user clicks back on the browser to prevent spammers submitting the form multiple times by clicking back, submit over and over again?

Comment: That is not the way to prevent spammers. They usually automate form submissions.

Comment: I do not think you can, you could use captcha to prevent multiple submissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 then you can set your FORM's Autocomplete function OFF.

```
<form action="youractionpage" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works. How secure is this feature in terms of bypassing this by spammers?

Comment: Spammers can submit your form multiple times as they want. Until you have a Captcha code in your Form. `autocomplete` will only empty your form, once submitted.

Answer (score 5):

You could use Javascript (or jQuery) to empty all inputs on page load.

jQuery example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').val('');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Was just about to suggest this, but the OP's idea doesn't actually prevent spamming.

Comment: I'm not sure if he really means spammers or non computer literate folks that press the back button, and then re-submit the form because they still see input on the page.

Answer (score 4):

It is always a good practice to use captcha in the form so that spammers can't bulk submit the form. Clearing the form won't be of much help as spammers use form filling extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the form fields, but since most browsers now use local cache to enhance performances, some of them might still remember the fields.

A way to ignore it is to set the page header's `Cache-Control` not to use cache.

However, there's still the matter of resend through refresh. After posting a form, pressing F5 will refresh the new page and resubmit the post data. To avoid that you'll need to clear the posted data. I'm not sure what is the best way to do that, but I've encountered one way: when you use `redirect` to another page in the server side, all `$_POST` data is erased.